# Custom Subversion Diff tool [Server Side]

Tags: shell, unix, svn, diff, server-side

There's a Subversion repository in my workplace for a programming language whose code is stored in some binary format (not text), and only runs in Unix (Solaris).  The only way to read/modify/diff code is with its propietary development environment in Unix.  I was able to make a unix shell script to utilize its diff tool with subversion; it converts code to text and then uses a diff tool for the comparison.  Alas, it's a client-side script and only runs if your working copy is in unix.

I was wondering if it was possible to call this script server-side (Hook?), whenever an "svn diff" is run, so it could be used from any environment the working copy is located, be it Unix, Windows (Tortoise), Mac, etc.

Comment: Why don't you store it in plain-text format ("converts code to text")? Maybe this solution would simplier. Or can't convert text to code?

Comment: this would mean that the hook script has to modify the content before delivering it to the client. Besides, that I think there is no hook for the diff command (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.reposhooks.html), I would consider this as a not clean solution... Maybe, at some point, you will need the actual diff... It could be a better solution to provide a different web service which you call to get the "custom diff"